# Setting up React on Node as a rendering daemon

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I've recently dived into React+Flux on the front-end, and I love it! But I want to also be able to use React on the back-end to avoid having to duplicate views and rendering logic.

I've seen that React supports server-side rendering if you use Node, but I do not use Node for my back-end logic.

So I'm wondering, can I set up a daemon written in Node that just renders HTML based on the data it receives and the root React component?

What I have in mind is to have my back-end application call this daemon with data already prepared (so that domain logic can live on my main back-end application), get HTML, and return that to the front-end.

Is this approach feasible? Has this been done before? I'd love some feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I see that it's been a month and there are still no comments, I will share some of my understandings.

We can use this setup:

- An **API** written in PHP or something similar that serves data.
- **Isomorphic React components** - render on the server, attach event listeners on the client.

  - **Server-side (Node)** - the React component uses AJAX calls to get its props from the API and embeds them into a `<script id="props" />` tag in the HTML as a JSON string.
  - **Client-side** - the component checks the script tag for props. If there is data, then it uses that to skip the re-rendering; if not (due to a server error or something), it can still use AJAX to get its props.

The main idea is that the website is **isomorphic** (server and client share the same code), so your existing front-end can be easily adapted to this setup.

A good place to start is a [simple example](https://github.com/ben-z/react-starter-coffee-tutorial) about isomorphic React components. [This tutorial](https://benzhang.xyz/reactjs/isomorphic/2015/05/02/isomorphic-webapp-react-express-coffee/) can also provide an overview to this subject.